# How to use .subscribe directly in Angular service?

Tags: angular, authentication, rxjs, subscribe

**SOLVED**

I'm implementing in Angular the state of user: isLogged true/false.

So whereever component I'm, I would verify if the user isLogged to show or hide stuff.
To do that I don't want just control if the accessToken is in the localstorage but I would check it asking to the server (with Http request) using the authService. So I would that isLogged() in authService give me back just true/false or set a boolean true/false. Usually I handle the 'res' and 'err' in the .subscribe in the Component but I wouldn't repeat it in each component. The problem is that I don't know how to use .subscribe directly in the service.

Athe the moment I'm using this solution. It works but I don't like it at all!!

```
isLogged() {
  return this.http
    .get<any>(this.isLoggedUrl)
    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
}

// I call this method in each component that needs to know if user is logged
isLoggedResHandle() {
  this.isLogged().subscribe(
    (res) => {
      if (res.status == 200) {
        this.loggedIn = true;
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err.error.message == 'TokenExpiredError') {
        this.loggedIn = false;
        //DO.. try refresh token. if refreshed: this.loggedIn = true
      } else {
        // for any other errors:
        this.loggedIn = false;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

**SOLUTION**

auth.service.ts

```
isLogged() {
    const accessToken = this.getAccessToken;
    if (typeof accessToken === 'undefined' || accessToken === null) {
      console.log('pieroooooooooo');
      this.loggedIn = false;
      return;
    }

    return this.http
      .get<any>(this.isLoggedUrl)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          if (res.status == 200) {
            this.loggedIn = true;
          }
        },
        (err) => {
          if (err.error.message == 'TokenExpiredError') {
            const refreshToken = this.getRefreshToken;
            if (typeof refreshToken !== 'undefined' || refreshToken !== null) {
              this.loggedIn = false;
            }

            this.loggedIn = false;
            // TODO: try to refresh it
          } else {
            this.loggedIn = false;
          }
        }
      );
  }

  getIsLogged() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }
```

header.component.ts or any component I want, something like:

```
<button class="btn btn-light my-2 my-sm-0" id="cartBtn" *ngIf="authService.getIsLogged()" [routerLink]="'/profile'"
      type="submit">
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
      Mio Profilo
</button>
```

app.component.ts // to keep the 'user status' updated also after a refresh:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.isLogged();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be a `ParentComponentClass` that implement the `isLoggedResHandle` logic and each of your Component that needs it can extends the class.

```
class ParentWithIsLoggedLogicCompoent {
  loggedIn = false
  
  constructor(private isLogged: IsLoggedService) {}

  isLoggedResHandle() {
    this.isLogged().subscribe(
      isLogged => this.loggedIn = isLogged,
      error => this.loggedIn = false
    )
  }
}

class YourOtherComponent extends ParentWithIsLoggedLogicCompoent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedResHandle();
  }
}
```

And you can extract the retry logic into the service with a `retryWhen` operator. I'm not sure if the syntax is good but it will be something like this:

```
isLogged() {
  return this.http
    .get<any>(this.isLoggedUrl)
    .pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => {
        errors.switchMap(error => {
          if(errors.error.message != 'TokenExpiredError') {
            throw errors
          }

          //DO.. try refresh token. if refreshed: this.loggedIn = true
        })
      }),    
      catchError(this.errorHandler)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thx, but I don't like this approach a lot because I should just for this goal keep different components  that have nothing in common under the same parent